# What is the "m=" attribute in a html <a> tag? (Plus tons of other attributes found in bing result source)

Tags: html

So I was looking through some source for a Bing images search result, and it seems the HTML for each hyperlink for each returned image is similar to:

```
<a href="#" 
ihk="HN.607992005913609849" 
m="{ns:&quot;images&quot;,k:&quot;5064&quot;,mid:&quot;3D11808868DB7B3BD88719756EECE65700723F87&quot;,surl:&quot;http://www.absoluteanime.com/naruto/kakashi.htm&quot;,imgurl:&quot;http://www.absoluteanime.com/naruto/kakashi.jpg&quot;,oh:&quot;225&quot;,tft:&quot;43&quot;,dls:&quot;images,5431&quot;,oi:&quot;http://www.absoluteanime.com/naruto/kakashi.jpg&quot;}" 
mid="3D11808868DB7B3BD88719756EECE65700723F87" 
onclick="return false;" 
t1="Kakashi Hatake" 
t2="640 x 480 · 32 kB · jpeg" 
t3="www.absoluteanime.com/naruto/kakashi.htm" 
h="ID=images,5064.1"
>
```

Now, looking at W3Schools documentation for the `<a>` tag [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp), there doesn't seem to be ANY documentation for most of these attributes, and after some decently extensive googling and irc lurking I can't find any info on them.

Am I completely misunderstanding these things, i.e are they not even attributes? (I am relatively new to HTML) Or are there somehow a ton more attributes out there that what is commonly documented?

I am interested in the m attribute mainly because it seems to be the only part of the the `<a>` tag that actually contains the url of the original image (as opposed to Bing's thumbnail).

Comment: Yes, that's custom stuff that Bing uses. They are bound to have some Javascript to look at these values. The browser itself (HTML itself) does not make use of it.

Comment: They kinda look like custom properties to me. You can create your own custom properties then reference them with javascript. I do the same thing with certain javascript plugins I've written. It makes things easier to allow for custom variables if you have a lot of "possible" actions for a link/element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, these are custom attributes.

Html tags allow you to put custom attributes on them and browsers simply ignore the ones that they do not understand.

Some sample usages of this feature in current use are:

- to store meta-data
- libraries like AngularJS use them to create directives

Comment: Thank you for the quick and informative answer and for (hopefully) not downvoting this question because of my ignorance, as others seem to have done :(

Comment: Do not worry about downvotes. That is a byproduct of a community moderated system. It helps in most cases. Good luck with your quest into the world of HTML!